# How do I add textAlign.left to an item in a class when displaying it in the view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an introduction screen page that displays three texts.To use the introduction screen, i imported the introduction_screen package in the yaml of the project. When running the project, the title is automatically aligning in the center instead of the left side of the screen.  How do I align the text on the left side of the screen? This is the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';
import 'package:project1/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:project1/utilities/constants.dart';



class Walkthrough extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WalkthroughState createState() => _WalkthroughState();
}

class _WalkthroughState extends State<Walkthrough> {

  List pageInfos = [
    {
      "title": "This \nis test \nnumber 1",
      "body": "",
    },
    {
      "title": "This \nis test \nnumber 2",
      "body": "",
    },
    {
      "title": "This \nis test \nnumber 3",
      "body": "",
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<PageViewModel> pages = [
      for(int i = 0; i<pageInfos.length; i++)
        _buildPageModel(pageInfos[i])
    ];

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()=>Future.value(false),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Constants.lightPrimary,
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0,200.0,0.0,0.0),
          child: IntroductionScreen(
            pages: pages,
            onDone: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                    return LoginScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            onSkip: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                    return LoginScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            showSkipButton: true,
            skip: Text("Skip"),
            next: Text(
              "Next",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                color: Constants.textPrimary,
              ),
            ),
            done: Text(
              "Done",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                color: Constants.textPrimary,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  _buildPageModel(Map item){
    return PageViewModel(
      title: item['title'],
      body: item['body'],
      decoration: PageDecoration(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          color: Constants.textPrimary,
        ),
        bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        pageColor: Constants.lightPrimary,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the title item of the page to align on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are providing 'title' which will be styled out as per the library implementation. If you want custom title styling, then use `titleWidget` instead: \

```dart
_buildPageModel(Map item){
    return PageViewModel(
      //title: item['title'],//<- remove this
      titleWidget: Text(item['title'], textAlign: TextAlign.start) // <- Use this instead
      body: item['body'],
      decoration: PageDecoration(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          color: Constants.textPrimary,
        ),
        bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        pageColor: Constants.lightPrimary,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This worked! except i moved the "]" that is beside the TextAlign.start beside the title. it worked like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an answer already provided but that did not work for me for some reason. That is why I am sharing what worked for me.

Use the below code,

```
_buildPageModel(Map item){
    return PageViewModel(
      titleWidget: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          item['title'],
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 25
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bodyWidget: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          item['body'],
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 25
          ),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: PageDecoration(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          color: Constants.textPrimary,
        ),
        bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        pageColor: Constants.lightPrimary,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: yes the answer above needs a little tweak with the "]" beside the start. Thank you for your answer both ways!